# Terraform unable to update Lambda with ECR image on new Image Publish

Tags: lambda, terraform, gitlab-ci, amazon-ecr, atlantis

Current Setup : I have created a GITLAB CI Pipeline to build a JAR and use the JAR in a docker Image Build and publishing the same to an AWS ECR Repository

Points to Note :

1. The image when it gets published is getting tagged using two tags one is the latest commit id that triggered the build and one is a custom tag called Latest.

The IaC being used is Terraform to deploy a Lambda Function that uses source file as ECR Repository URI.

image_uri = ECR Repo UrL:latest

On subsequent builds when new image is built the latest tag gets taken out from the old image and gets attached to the new image.

When i am trying to run Terraform Plan its unable to detect change in the Image even when the SHA value of the new image with latest tag has changed.

```
data "aws_ecr_repository" "service" {
  name = "ecr-repository"
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "test_lambda" {
  image_uri = “${data.aws_ecr_repository.service.repository_url}:latest”
  function_name = "lambda_function_name"
  role          = aws_iam_role.iam_for_lambda.arn
  handler       = "index.test"
  runtime = "nodejs16.x"

  environment {
    variables = {
      foo = "bar"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Would be helpful if you post some piece of code.

Comment: data "aws_ecr_repository" "service" {
  name = "ecr-repository"
}

Comment: @JuanFontes updated the code in Question

Comment: This is because you are using `latest` tag, which never changes in Terraform, so Terraform has no idea that it needs to update anything. You should change your Terraform code to take the commit ID as an input variable, and use that as the tag.